# Can we get a scrollbar in the tag selection box?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-dropdown

When adding or editing tags, and you enter part of a tag, a tag dropdown appears with up to 6 selections in it (see pic below).  For some of the more popular choices, this isn't enough, and then I have to guess until I get the tag I want (guess the next few letter or symbols for auto-complete to change out the 6).  It's especially frustrating if the tag doesn't exist (as many don't on the new Meta SO), since you can't be sure that your're just guessing wrong.  Many times I just end up having to open another window and go the the tag search page.

[image: Tag Selection Box]

How about we add a scrollbar to that box, or some other mechanism to allow more tag choices?

Comment: Can't you just keep typing so that the autosuggest feature autosuggests the item you're after? That's far quicker than scrolling an ever-changingly long scrollbar.

Comment: @JonW, that's what I mean by guessing.  I have to guess what letters or symbols (like hyphen) are next.

Comment: I would say that is where synonyms come in though. Chances are if someone wants to call a tag something different to the norm then someone would've already tried and a synonym is therefore born. I don't think a scrollbar of all the millions of tags with `c***` or whatever is a more user-friendly approach than limiting it to the most popular 6 and then autocompleting the rest.

Comment: (I now notice my example search string of `C` and some wildcards `*` looks a bit more sweary than I intended there! I just figured there were lots of tags starting with 'C'!)

Comment: @JonW, well, I just got caught this morning, unable to guess.  It gets real hard when the tag doesn't exist, because you don't know if you're just guessing wrong.  I've edited in the auto-complete part.

Comment: You don't need to worry about where the hyphens are; they seem to be ignored for suggestion purposes. E.g., typing `tagsy` gets [tag-synonyms] as a possibility.